# How to properly link these articles?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, symfony-1.2

I am trying to link articles with one another. The scenario is define below

**Take articles A, B and C.**

- Admin links A to B. So, we automatically add links for B to A.
- Admin links B to C. So, we automatically add links for C to B (normal
  scenario) as well as C to A (because B is linked to A). ( **How can i do this? I tried the below code but can't move forward** )
- Admin deletes the link from B to C. So, we automatically delete links
  for C to B as well as C to A.

My code:

```
 public function executeLinkarticle(sfWebRequest $request) {

        $this->articleId = $request->getParameter('id');
        if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
            $articles = $request->getParameter('articles');
            $articleId = $request->getParameter('articleId');
            foreach ($articles as $linkedArticleId) {
                //Linking A To B
                $linkedArticleObj =  new BlogArticleLinkedArticle();
                $linkedArticleObj->setArticleId($articleId);
                $linkedArticleObj->setLinkedArticleId($linkedArticleId);
                $linkedArticleObj->save();

                //Linking B To A
                $linkedArticleObj =  new BlogArticleLinkedArticle();
                $linkedArticleObj->setArticleId($linkedArticleId);
                $linkedArticleObj->setLinkedArticleId($articleId);
                $linkedArticleObj->save();

                //linking C to A code
                Checking the Database Table IF B is LINKED WITH A(i.e already linked) THEN how to link C to A ?

            }
            return $this->renderText();
        }
    }
```

**Table Structure**

```
ID   |    ARTICLE_ID  |    LINKED_ARTICLE_ID
```

Comment: What would be `C` id in your code? You first need to find `C` by `A & B` (query?) then links `C` to `A`

Comment: Looks like a simple recursive approach: if you place a link from X to Y and a link from Y to Z, Z should check if there are other incoming links for Y and modify them

Comment: It looks like you are trying to persist a tree structure. You could try a different pattern for storing this information in the database, e.g. by using a NestedSet approach. See: http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/